# ebproof not working with metropolis beamer theme

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis, ebproof

I am trying to use the metropolis theme with `beamer` and the package `ebproof` on overleaf. (It seems this is an overleaf specific problem.)  However, `ebproof'`s `prooftree` environment is not working.

Here is an example of the error:
[image]

And the TeX that generated it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{ebproof}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

$$\begin{prooftree} 
\hypo{A}
\infer1{B}
\end{prooftree}$$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: I am using overleaf.  I just tried to compile it on my computer and it worked. I guess this is a solution in that I can work on my computer rather than overleaf.

Comment: and didn't you see that you get lots of error messages? That is something that you should check and mention in such a question.

Comment: Seems to work fine on overleaf with TL2017 or newer